# Coding Style for GCC ARM Optimization levels

Tags: performance, gcc, optimization

I've been doing embedded firmware since 1977 but I have never enabled optimization on any of the compilers I've used.

I'm working with the GCC ARM compiler for a CM4 micro.

Code runs as expected with NO optimization.

I use a lot of structures and pointers in my code.

I use volatile when a variable can change from within an interrupt routine.

I recently need to speed up execution of my code so I used optimization level -Og (first time ever enabling optimization) - which still gives good debugging and increased performance where I wanted it.

My issue/concern is the code behaves really flacky!!!

It behaves OK - then I make a small change - and it mis-behaves -- changes each time I run the compiler - almost like there is an issue with address alignment or instructions have been completely removed.

I can change some variables to volatile and that also changes behavior but I don't understand why that would affect how global variables (not modified in an interrupt routine) would have a positive change in behavior.

I'm about ready to give up with over-all optimization and look at using function specific optimization since I know which functions affect the performance I'm trying to improve.

Can anyone explain how coding style can be impacted negatively with optimization?

Any good documents that address coding style with optimization in mind?

Does GCC function level optimization work well?

Thanks.

Joe

Comment: Why do you blame your tools before yourself? Have you considered the possibility that your code may be invoking _undefined behaviour_, but that this manifests itself only when GCC tries to optimize harder? You should 1) Code while knowing and keeping in mind the rules of C. 2) Compile with harsh warning settings like `-Wall -Wextra` to see the compiler's diagnoses, and fix those; 3) Run your code with ASan/UBSan or under Valgrind to identify any remaining problems. 4) Write testcases.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I don't understand your soapbox stand.  The title and my post all suggest it may be my coding style - so I do blame myself first.  Thanks for the warning info - i'll try it

Comment: I *have* seen compiler bugs, so _in theory_ you could be facing one. But these days, GCC is some of the most heavily used compiler software worldwide, and happening upon an optimizer bug is rare. Much more likely is that your avoidance of optimization or warning flags has allowed you to slip into a habit of writing code that relies on UB (Like type punning `*(T*)&var` or aliasing), and GCC's optimizers simply do what the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) allows a compiler to do.

Comment: I'll add one small tip. Some GCC warnings might appear _only_ at `-O0` because they concern code that is optimized out (rightly or wrongly), whereas some GCC warnings require analysis passes that are _only_ enabled at `-O1` and above. So it's valuable to compile both w/ and w/o optimizations enabled regularly.

Comment: Avoidance of optimization - yes.  Avoidance of warnings - no.  No aliasing.  No multiple instructions on a single line.  My coding style is keep it plain and simple for long term maintenance.The issue has to be me doing something that's why I asked for comments as to how I can identify them.

Comment: I engaged -Wall (thanks - I did not know about that) and 99% of all the warning are "pointer-sign" -- I'm using unsigned char* for all byte pointers but warnings show when passed into string functions that want a char* (other compilers I've used allowed the two to be treated  the same).  Besides putting a pragma in each on my files to turn -Wall on, is there a better way to have some files with warning and some without?  i.e. - I use FreeRtos - not as a library but compiled along with my files.  I don't want to investigate warnings with 3rd party source files.

Comment: Mmmmm. You can disable those warnings with `-Wno-pointer-sign`. Aside from the warning pragmas, you can use `#pragma GCC diagnostic push` and `pop` to modify the set of enabled warnings anywhere within a file. But if your code is open-source it would probably help to link us to your work so we can see what's most liable to break.

Comment: Used -Wall and -Wextra in all my files.  Very clean - no issue found.  I used the following in all files.  
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wextra"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpointer-sign"

Comment: Without seeing your code I'm somewhat shooting in the dark here, but another possibility is that you're doing inter-thread communication over shared memory, but improperly labeling your shared memory accesses, thus allowing the compiler to perform invalid optimizations or at least put the CPU in a position to perform an incorrect reordering. Are you protecting inter-thread communications with mutexes/locks/memory fences/memory barriers?  `volatile`.is not always the whole solution.

Comment: I use queues for inter-thread communication.  No shared global memory.

Comment: I'm somewhat at a loss now... Is the bug deterministic? Can you put up the snippet of (non-working) code w/ (and w/o) the `volatile` so we can stare at it, maybe even with a disassembly?

Comment: If I can isolate the problem code, I can resolve it.

Comment: Problem is the behavior ends up so screwy, I'm having trouble actually tracking down the problem code snippet.  I added pragma optimization to each file (level -o2) so I can selectively turn off optimization by file to locate problem area.

Comment: If you have the opportunity to run your code in a non-embedded environment, I can also suggest using some of the sanitisers. Have a look at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html, in particular the -fsanitize=address and -fsanitize=undefined options that will add runtime instrumentation to your code that will notify you when your code exhibits undefined behaviour. They don't catch everything, but they can help a lot